# How to get the index/position where difference of values exceeds a threshold?

Tags: r

I have this data frame:

```
 > new
        group       date      median
    1    1       2012-07-01  1.839646
    2    1       2012-08-01  1.839646
    3    2       2012-09-01  1.839646
    4    2       2012-10-01  1.839646
    5    3       2012-11-01  1.839646
    6    3       2012-12-01  1.839646
    7    4       2013-01-01  5.554302
    8    4       2013-02-01  5.554302
    9    5       2013-03-01  5.554302
    10   5       2013-04-01  5.554302
    11   6       2013-05-01  5.554302
    12   6       2013-06-01  5.554302
    13   7       2013-07-01  2.226150
    14   7       2013-08-01  2.226150
    15   8       2013-09-01  2.226150
    16   8       2013-10-01  2.226150
    17   9       2013-11-01  2.226150
    18   9       2013-12-01  2.226150
```

What I want to do now is, I want to compare the median values and if the difference of for example the first and the second unique value exceeds a certain limit, then give me the location where this happens.

**Step-by-step:**
In this example, I have three unique median values `(1.839646,5.554302,2.226150)`

1) Compare the first and second unique value. If the difference is bigger than (for example) 50% of the first value, then give me the position of last first value:

**So:**

**a)** abs(1.839646 - 5.554302) = 3,714656

**b)** 50 % of 1.839646 is 0.919823

**c)** 3,714656 is bigger than 0.919823

**d)** get index of where this happens: at index 6 (which is at date 2012-12-01)

The same for the second and third (unique) value.

Comment: do you always want the last date where the difference exceeds your threshold?

Comment: Hey Mike! Yes, always the last date. I will plot a vertical line afterwards at this index and for my data it is the best solution for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your vector of medians `x`:

```
# sample data
x = rep(c(1.839646,5.554302,2.226150), each = 6)
which(c(0, abs(diff(x))) > 0.5 * x) - 1
# [1] 6 12
```

Demo on your data:

```
new = read.table(text = "        group       date      median
    1    1       2012-07-01  1.839646
    2    1       2012-08-01  1.839646
    3    2       2012-09-01  1.839646
    4    2       2012-10-01  1.839646
    5    3       2012-11-01  1.839646
    6    3       2012-12-01  1.839646
    7    4       2013-01-01  5.554302
    8    4       2013-02-01  5.554302
    9    5       2013-03-01  5.554302
    10   5       2013-04-01  5.554302
    11   6       2013-05-01  5.554302
    12   6       2013-06-01  5.554302
    13   7       2013-07-01  2.226150
    14   7       2013-08-01  2.226150
    15   8       2013-09-01  2.226150
    16   8       2013-10-01  2.226150
    17   9       2013-11-01  2.226150
    18   9       2013-12-01  2.226150", header = TRUE)

results = which(c(0, abs(diff(new$median))) > 0.5 * new$median) - 1
results
# [1] 6 12
new$date[results]
# [1] 2012-12-01 2013-06-01
```

Comment: Edited to add in `abs()`

Comment: Hi Gregor, thanks for your nice answer! This does work, but I am missing for this data set another 'breakpoint' between the second (5.554302) and third (2.226150) value.

Comment: I just saw your edit, now it works 100% the way I want it. Thanks!